# how to get a count of records from Table B to place next to the name of each row in Table A

Tags: php, mysql

I have so many problems trying to understand this, so forgive me for what's most likely a repeat question.

I have 2 tables, one called "category" and one called "items". Each row in "items" has a category_id field that matches the category_id field in the "category" table.

In one mysql statement, I want to get a row count for each category_id in "items", but also retrieve the category_name in "category", so I can print out a list of categories like this:

- Foo (3)
- Bar (1)
- Duh (6)

The questions I've found here so far only seem to return the category_id's from "items", so the result would look like this:

- 1 (3)
- 2 (1)
- 3 (6)

Follow? I'm sure it can be done in one mysql statement, so far I've had to resort to two separate queries for the sole purpose of getting that little number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you;

```
SELECT c.name AS theName, COUNT(i.id) AS theCount
FROM category AS c JOIN items AS i ON i.category_id = c.id
GROUP BY i.category_id
```

//Edit

Sorry I should then explain this.

`Select` Is grabbing the category name and the count of the items.

`From` Is doing a join that will bind items and categories together.

`Group By` Is ensuring that the Category ID is the unique thing in the query.

Comment: wow, thanks for the quick answer! I assume that "c" and "i" are replaced with the actual table names for the category & items tables?

Comment: Yeah, in the FROM part you can do tableName AS wibble then you can refer to tableName as wibble from then on, it just makes things shorter and easier to read (sometimes!)

Comment: oh, that's cool...and explains the "items AS i" part. This JOIN stuff is very confusing but I think I understand. Thank you very much!!